# framebuffer without depth attachment in shadow mapping

Tags: opengl

In my shadow map implementation, i am attaching color attachment to my fbo and i don't have any depth attachment. I have depth test enabled for rendering onto that FBO. With this implementation I get shadows correctly. I am wondering how it works without depth attachment. Can somebody explain me this? 
I use color attachment to store my depth values as

```
color = vec4(gl_FragCoord.z,gl_FragCoord.z,gl_FragCoord.z,1.0);
```

Comment: Well, _it doesn't_. But without any details, it is impossible to explain what exactly is happening.

Comment: Define "this works".

Comment: @NicolBolas updated question.

Comment: I don't understand what you don't expect to "work". You seem to be trying to provide the bare minimum of information, when we have absolutely no idea what you're actually doing or seeing or expecting to see. We don't know anything about your scene, your shadows, or anything at all. All I can see is that you're taking your Z value (presumably in a fragment shader) and storing that in a color buffer, then presumably doing something involving shadows with that. And you seem to believe that it "works" and you don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

This resembles no depth attachment I have ever seen (I realize you are trying to use a color attachment in its place); you are shoehorning four components into something that only needs one. There is defined behavior for reading from the 2<sup>nd</sup>, 3<sup>rd</sup> and 4<sup>th</sup> components of a depth attachment even though they do not exist, but writing to them is effectively meaningless.

If you intend to use a color texture to serve as a depth texture, then make sure it has high single-component precision (e.g. try something like `GL_R32F`) and do not waste storage with the 2<sup>nd</sup>, 3<sup>rd</sup> and 4<sup>th</sup> components. Alternatively, you could pack parts of a 32-bit, 24-bit or 16-bit fixed-point value across multiple components and unpack them later - this is pretty unorthodox on anything modern.

---

> > I am wondering how it works without depth attachment.

Generally it will not work.

You have just told us you have no depth attachment but the depth test is enabled ... what is that going to accomplish?

You may not want to draw to a depth texture for some reason, but you are at the very least, going to need a renderbuffer depth attachment for there to be anything in the framebuffer to actually test against.